# Prove that for every connected graph $G$ of order $n$ and diameter $d$ , $\chi(G)\leq n-d+1$

Tags: graph-theory

Prove that for every connected graph $G$ of order $n$ and diameter $d$ , $\chi(G)\leq n-d+1$

The book explain this problem very briefly, so I'm not sure I understand it. They say look at the $v_0-v_d$ geodesic and got the path $P=v_0,...,v_d$ with length $d$ and I will have the result, but I can't see how. I can see that every path has $\chi(P)=2$. I also know that $\chi(G) \leq n-\alpha(G)+1$. Is there a connection between $d$ and $\alpha(G)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $P$ be a shortest $d$-path between two vertices  $u,v$ of $G.$ Notice that the graph induced by $V(P)$ is precisely this path (otherwise you'd get a shorter path). So if you remove the vertices $V(P)-\{u,v\}$ from $G$ you obtain a graph $G'$ with $n-d-1$ vertices.

Hence $G'$ can be colored with $n-d-1$ colors and by introducing the edges of $P$ you (at worst) need two new colors.

Another way one can visualize this is as follows your graph is a subgraph of the join of $P$ and $G'.$ You can color $G'$ with$n-d-1$ colors. Now at the very worse two (adjacent) vertices of $P$ are adjacent with all vertices of $G'$ and hence you need to introduce two new colors in order to properly color $G.$

Comment: Why do you need Brook's theorem here? Isn't it obvious that $G'$ can be colored with $n-d-1$ colors because it has that many vertices?

Comment: @ctlaltdefeat Good point. Edited my answer.